# How can I test Google Voice Assistant apps in the Desktop Head Unit?

Tags: android, google-assistant-sdk

I am facing an issue while testing "Google Voice Assistant" apps for Android Auto. I am using DHU for that. But it always says "The {application_name} is not supported on this device", while the app works on mobile device.

Comment: Try adding target devices to the manifest.

Comment: Did you manage to get this working?

Comment: Not yet, did you got any success @LazyBrush

Comment: Not yet, when I get a response from Google, I'll update this thread.

Comment: @LazyBrush did you got any update

Comment: Sorry, no update.